# Pig data cleaning based on date

Tags: apache-pig, data-cleaning

I have 2 datasets as shown below:
1. ID and location

```
{ID, beginning year, ending year, location}.
```

sample:

```
(1001, 2010, 2012, CA)
(1001, 2013, 2015, WA)
(1002, 2009, 2015, AZ)
(1003, 2014, 2015, FL)
```

2. ID and connection

```
{ID1, ID2, connection creating date}
```

sample:

```
(1001, 1002, 2013)
(1001, 1003, 2014)
```

I want to count the number of connections based on location and year. I assume once the connection is created, it never expires. The results I am looking for is below

```
{Location 1, Location2, year, number of connections}
```

In the example above, it should be:

```
(WA, AZ,2013,1)
(WA, AZ,2014,1)
(WA, AZ,2015,1)
(WA, FL,2014,1)
(WA, FL,2015,1)
```

Does anyone know how to accomplish that in Apache pig?

Comment: Would you like to add what you've tried already? And how are you getting `WA, AZ,2015` from the above data?

Comment: @cricket_007 WA AZ 2015 is based on the connection between 1001 and 1002 since 2013. One approach I am thinking about is to create all information for every year rather only the beginning and ending year, then I join the id connection table with the id location table based on year and id, then group and count the connections between locations. I have two problems here: 1.how to generate the yearly information, 2. this will significantly increase the data size, is there other way to do it?

Comment: Well, does it have to be in the Pig? You will be have more programmatic access to the data and logic constructs in Spark

Comment: Unfortunately, it has too be. Thank you all the same!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in your comment, we will at some point need to move to yearly information. To minimizes impact of data size bloat up, we need to move it as far down as possible in our pig script.
First thing we need to do is the following data translation:

```
{ID1, ID2, connection creating date} -> {Location1, Location2, start_year, end_year}
```

This can be achived with the following pig script statements:

```
locationData = LOAD 'path1' USING PigStorage('\t') AS (ID:chararray, beginning_year:long, ending_year:long, location:chararray);
connectionData = LOAD 'path2' USING PigStorage('\t') AS (ID1:chararray, ID2:chararray, connection_year:long);

partialJoin = JOIN connectionData USING ID1, locationData USING ID;
partialExtracted = FOREACH partialJoin GENERATE
                           ID2,
                           connection_year,
                           location AS location1,
                           (beginning_year > connection_year ? beginning_year : connection_year) AS start_year,
                           ending_year AS end_year;

fullJoin = JOIN partialExtracted USING ID2, locationData USING ID;
fullExtracted = FOREACH fullJoin GENERATE,
                           location1,
                           location AS location2,
                           (beginning_year > start_year ? beginning_year : start_year) AS start_year,
                           (ending_year < end_year ? ending_year : end_year ) AS end_year;

fullFiltered = FILTER fullExtracted BY (end_year < start_year);
```

We are now ready to explode the data to get yearly information. Essentially, the following data translation needs to happen:

```
{Location1, Location2, start_year, end_year} -> {Location1, Location2, year}
e.g.
WA, AZ, 2013, 2015
->
WA, AZ, 2013
WA, AZ, 2014
WA, AZ, 2015
```

Here a UDF is unavoidable. We will need a UDF which takes start year and end year and returns a bag of the range of years. You should be able to follow online tutorial to write your UDF. Lets say this UDF is called getYearRange(). Your script will look as follows:

```
fullExploded = FOREACH fullFiltered GENERATE
                       location1, location2,
                       FLATTEN(getYearRange(start_year, end_year)) AS year;
```

All that remains is a GROUP BY to get your final counts:

```
fullGrouped = GROUP fullExploded BY (location1, location2, year);
finalOutput = FOREACH fullGrouped GENERATE 
              FLATTEN(group) AS (location1, location2, year),
              COUNT(fullExploded) AS count;
```

The above describes the data flow. You might need to add additional steps to take care of edge cases and ensure data sanity.